# Adding entries to LinkedList inside ConcurrentHashMap not working

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list

I have a ConcurrentHashMap that contains a string as a key and LinkedList as a value. The size of the list should not be more than 5. I am trying to add some elements to the list but when I print out the Map I see only the last added element. Here is my code:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedList<Date>> userDisconnectLogs = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedList<Date>>();

public void addNewDateEntry(String userId, LinkedList<Date> timeStamps) {
    if (timeStamps.size() >= 5) {
        timeStamps.poll();
        timeStamps.add(new Date());
        userDisconnectLogs.put(userId, timeStamps);
    } else {
        timeStamps.add(new Date());
        userDisconnectLogs.put(userId, timeStamps);
    }

    for (Entry<String, LinkedList<Date>> entry : userDisconnectLogs
            .entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey().toString();
        ;
        LinkedList<Date> value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + value.size());
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: your key is same all the time.

Comment: Show the code where you are calling `addNewDateEntry()`?

Comment: it is something like that
`userService.addNewDateEntry(userService.getUserIdByPrincipal(disconnectedUser), (LinkedList<Date>) timeStamps);`

Comment: And what value is `timeStamps` being given? And as a side note, why do you need to cast it?

Answer (score 0):

Here for hashMap key must be unique. And from this code it seems key is always same so all the time it will overrite the data.

Comment: Yes it will be the same, but I want the value of the LinkedList corresponding to that key to increase.

Comment: For hashmap key must be unique that is first constrain, so you can either increase your userid by a number and make it unique or you can select other unique key.

Comment: The question is not related to the key, I know it must be unique. My problem is I cannot add more than one element to the LinkedList that represents the value.

Comment: System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + value.size());, Here you have write value.size() instead of value.get(index) ,  So you want to print size or value??.

Comment: Is that problem you are facing??